# C++: Find minimum in array only among elements with specified indices

Tags: python, c++, arrays, lambda, minimum

I couldn't find a solution to the following problem:

I am trying to find the minimum in a C++ array, but without looking at all elements inside, only among elements that have a specified index.
E.g., if I am given an index k, and an array `int* mylist = int[n]`, then I want to look for the minimal element in mylist only in a "sublist" of elements, where e.g. the index of the respective elements i fulfills `i%n = k`.
In Python, this can be easily solved by

```
min([mylist[i]  for i in range(n) if i%n==k]),
```

but afaik, there is no equivalent in C++. Also, lambda functions do not do the trick, as far as I understood.

Any idea how to do this efficiently? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: there is no equivalent in C++. I don't agree with that ..there is lambda as well as there is stl to find min

Comment: So far, I couldn't figure out how to use a lambda in that case, but I was hoping that I did not have to use a loop for this, I just don't know how

Comment: std::vector<int>::iterator result = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v),[] (int val) {
            return val%n = k;);    val%n = k (you can put your expression

Comment: std::begin(v), std::end(v) , you can fix the index in begin and end

Comment: boost [range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors.html) might contain what you need. However, I'd go with a loop. It's only a few lines of code and probably the most efficient way (this is c++ not python!)

Comment: What do you mean by efficiently?  Code wise?  Excution time wise?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of why standard algorithms work with iterators rather than directly with containers/collections. It allows you to write an iterator that embodies the indices you care about.

The problem is that writing an iterator is more work than most people would like, or consider justified for this simple of a task. Boost has some utilities to make it easier to implement iterators, such as a [filter iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html), but as far as I know these are applied based only on the *content* of the collection, not the indices.

The code involved in creating an `index_filter` would be fairly trivial (e.g., should be easy to extrapolate from the code for `filter_iterator` linked above), but there's more boiler-plate there than most people would like. Unless you're doing things like this pretty regularly, it may be difficult to justify.

Answer (score 1):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do something similar to:

```
for (auto e : v | ranges::view::drop(3) | ranges::view::stride(5)) {
    std::cout << e << std::endl;   
}
```

so you iterate over index `5 * k + 3`.

And you can call `ranges::min_element` on resulting view:

```
auto view = v | ranges::view::drop(3) | ranges::view::stride(5);
auto it = ranges::min_element(view);
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8488e199d76ba27c)

Answer (score 0):

`i % n = k` will be a either:

1. k if `k < n`
2. `[]` empty that is, if `k > n`

This is because i varies from `0 to n`

Hence there will be only one or no elements.

For clarity: `n = 50; print([i%n for i in range(n)])` , gives:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
```

That is, unique values between `0 to n-1`

Comment: I think you're taking the example code more literally than it was intended. I'd assume that the `i%n` is really `i%m`. More generally, it's not necessarily about remainders at all--just a function that selects some subset of the indices.

Comment: Ya I understand, that problem is quite hard to achieve as a one-liner as in case of python. But this is just to answer OP's problem if it really were the case.

Comment: It's right, I didn't mean the example that literally, in fact it's the case that n*n is the length of the array, not n. That's why there is more than one element possible, but thank you anyway for clarifying this.